# C# serial IO.port : Serial Data Parsing not responding fast enough?

Tags: c#, serial-port, msp430, virtual-serial-port

Good day all,

First let me say that I am new to C#, as I am more into embedded C.

I am trying to read a 2Hz signal from a signal generator using the MSP430FR5739 (TI-microcontroller). I sample the analog value using the onboard ADC at 1024 samples in 1MHz cycle and send it through UART comms with a 9600 baudrate using a USB-to-Serial. I have that all working quite perfectly.... (as I have tested this through a hyper-terminal, and arduino's serial monitor)

The data sent,looks like this:(each on a new line)

0

0

0

16

51

123

157

227

250

315

338

384

404
.....

As you can see, each data is displayed on a new line....but here is my problem.

Currently I am using this C# code to read and parse the data, in an application that displays it, which looks like this:

[Received Data][1]

Here is the problem on the UI application:

When the 2Hz signal changes (e.g. from sin-wave to square-wave, or the peak-peak value changes), it takes FOREVER for the data to change in my application. If I read the signal data through a hyper-terminal or arduino's serial monitor, as soon as the value of the signal changes, so does the data...but NOT in this application.  I think, I am reading the Serial port correctly, but I am thinking there is some sort of buffer that fills up, and then it takes forever for this buffer to then reach the point where the signal changed, and then display it. I really need to understand what is going on....I have tried to find possible solution on the Internet for a solution, but I have not found any meaningful one.

Why can't I read this in real time, as the serial console does?

```
/***function for listening incoming data on the serial COM port***/
    private void ComPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        { 
            if (serialPort.ReadBufferSize != 0)
            {
                ReceivedData = ComPort.ReadLine();      //read each data line whenever the buffer size is not zero
                this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayData)); //call another thread to write data on rtxtDisplay
            }
        }
        catch(TimeoutException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, "Buffer error!", "TIMEOUT EXCEPTION", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
    }

    /***function to display the received***/
    private void DisplayData(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ckBoxAutoscroll.Checked == true)
            {
                rtxtDataRx.AppendText(ReceivedData);   //display each data received
                rtxtDataRx.SelectionStart = rtxtDataRx.Text.Length - 1;
                rtxtDataRx.ScrollToCaret();                     //auto scroll the rich textbox with incoming data
            }
            else
            {
                rtxtDataRx.AppendText(ReceivedData);   //display each data received
                rtxtDataRx.SelectionStart = rtxtDataRx.Text.Length - 1;
            }                

            //for testing the signal generator
            val1 = Convert.ToDouble(ReceivedData);
            val1 = (val1 * 0.00352);
            num1 = Math.Round(val1, 2);
            voltage = Convert.ToString(num1);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //catch any bug and display this message
            MessageBox.Show(this, "Transmission jammed!", "UART COMs ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you checking `ReadBufferSize`?  It can never be 0.  Also, I would check for `Exception` instead of just `TimeoutException`.  Looks like `ReceivedData` isn't getting updated.

Comment: As Jim suggested, I wouldn't check for the `ReadBufferSize` for when to update your display.  If you know there is a <CR><LF> then I would look for that or why even check at all?  Just let the data received event update the GUI thread, it's not going to fire unless there are characters coming in.

Comment: This is a traditional *fire-hose bug*.  Hyper-terminal and Arduino's serial monitor were designed by their programmers to deal with a large amount of data sent by a device.  They typically use a fixed-size circular buffer for the data and update the screen at a pace that's suitable for programmer's eyes.  RichTextBox is *nothing* like that.  Every AppendText() call requires it to re-allocate its internal text buffer and makes it repaint itself.  Very fast, but the more data in the buffer the longer that takes.  It won't take long before it takes *more* time than receiving a line of text.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for the clear explanation of how the buffer works on the other applications such as Hyper-terminal and Arduino's serial monitor. Instead of using the AppendText()  function in the RichTextBox; is there another way which I could use in order to execute the incoming data in real-time?